# Не работает код jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает код, не пойму почему. Консоль отображает пустой массив linesArray.

```js
var linesArray = [];

jQuery.get('words.txt', function(data) {
  linesArray = data.split(/\s+/);
}, 'text');

console.log(linesArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Содержание файла words.txt:
1
2
3

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без jQuery:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'words.txt', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status == 200) {
   linesArray = data.split(/\s+/);
   console.log('words.txt >', linesArray);
}
```

попробуйте, и если не работает смотрите во вкладке `network` что приходит в ответ на Ваш запрос, или выполняется-ли запрос